# R model for proportional odds methodology for scale variable that allows for variable improvements

Tags: r, ordinal-data, clinical-trials, ordered-logit, pre-post-comparison

I'm looking to understand what would be the most appropriate R model for fitting a clinical dataset in which the dependent variable is the change in a 5-point scale and the end of treatment.

The data has the below variables and form, question under 's2_improv':

- arm - 2 level factor            - 'trt' for treatment, 'pbo' for placebo
- b1  - continuous positive float - a biomarker that is measured
  at baseline known to correlate with
  disease severity
- s1  - scale - 60 point scale, increments of 1 - a scale indicating patient
  impairment at baseline, given the range, I believe treating it
  as a continuous variable is fine
- s2_base - scale - baseline value of the 5 point scale used to measure patient
  improvement, values are c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- s2_improv - change in the s2 scale from baseline to end of treatment, patients
  can start at any scale number and end at any scale number [0-5], so
  a patient might go from 5 to 3 or 4 to 2 and both would have a 2 value

Question: My understanding is proportional odds models (ex: polr()) are typically used
for stepwise data like changes in scales, however, the intercept outputs
are focused on 1-point changes, here since patients can change by a variable
amount of steps, what would be the best model to assess whether patients
on the treatment arm were proportionally more likely to improve [1-5] points?

DATA

```
arm     b1        s1     s2_base     s2_improv
trt     799       24        4             0
trt     201       24        3             1
trt     100       24        4             2
pbo     1,231     3         4             3
pbo     3,412     0         5             1
trt     730       26        4             3
pbo     517       30        4             4
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "however, the intercept outputs are focused on 1-point changes, here **since patients can change by a variable amount of steps**"?